# how to set platform specific css (different styles for android and ios) in ionic4

Tags: css, sass, angular7, ionic4

To set specific styles to "ListingPage" for android and ios in ionic 3, I was using below structure in .scss file of the "Listing" page/component:

```
.ios {  // for ios
    page-listing { // page selector
        // css enclosed in class or id selectors
    }
}

.md {  // for android
    page-listing { // page selector
        // css enclosed in class or id selectors
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same platform specific styling in ionic4.

Answer (score 5):

I think you now have to manually add an element with class/id in your component.

```
<div class="page-listing">Something</div>

.page-listing {
   color: red;
}

.ios .page-listing {
   color: yellow;
}

.md .page-listing {
   color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles/

The whole documentation is already provided by ionic team.Please go through it.

```
<html class="md"> //for android
<html class="ios"> //for ios
```

its working for me